# ¿Cómo transformar una cadena de un archivo que pertenece a una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex

Quiero hacer programa python que modifica cada lineas de un archivo txt cuando empieza con una letra y una paréntesis. Por ejemplo :

```
Option histoire-géographie

Cette épreuve consiste à rédiger, sans l'aide d'une documentation, une dissertation portant sur l'un des thèmes d'histoire ou de géographie figurant au programme défini ci-après.

I. - Histoire

Le programme porte sur l'histoire de la France et du monde de 1945 à nos jours.
1° La construction du monde contemporain (de 1945 aux années 1960) :
a) Le monde en 1945.
b) Le modèle communiste et son expansion mondiale.
c) Puissance et influence du modèle américain.
d) La renaissance de l'Europe et ses limites.
e) La fin des empires coloniaux.
f) Un monde bipolaire : guerre froide et coexistence pacifique.
2° La croissance et la crise (des années 1950 aux années 1990) :
a) La croissance économique et la société de la prospérité (1950-1973).
b) Les relations Est-Ouest à l'heure de l'équilibre.
c) Le tiers-monde à l'écart de la croissance.
d) La longue crise, sa signification et ses retombées sociales.
e) L'échec du modèle communiste en Europe et la fin de l'URSS.
f) L'élaboration d'un nouvel ordre mondial dominé par l'hyperpuissance américaine.
3° La France depuis 1945 :
a) La reconstruction politique et économique de la France après 1945.
b) Les guerres coloniales et l'échec de la IVe République.
c) Naissance et consolidation de la Ve République (1958-1969).
d) La Ve République après 1969 : les expériences néo-gaullistes, libérales, socialistes.
e) L'évolution de la Ve République : alternances, cohabitations, mutations (1986-2013).
f) Les mutations sociales et culturelles depuis 1945.
4° Le monde au début du XXIe siècle :
a) L'hyperpuissance américaine.
b) Les enjeux de la construction européenne.
c) Les destins contrastés des anciens pays socialistes.
d) La diversité des tiers-mondes : entre émergence(s) et domination(s).
e) Les contrastes de l'aire asiatique et le géant chinois .
f) La percée de l'islam intégriste et la menace du terrorisme.

II. - Géographie

1° Les milieux naturels :
a) Les domaines climatiques et les milieux naturels.
b) Les écosystèmes.
2° Les grands ensembles régionaux du monde :
a) Les aires culturelles.
b) La triade (Amérique du Nord, Europe, Asie orientale) et la globalisation.
3° L'espace urbain :
a) La ville.
b) L'urbanisation dans le monde.
c) Les réseaux urbains en France et en Europe.
d) L'espace urbain et les sociétés urbaines.
4° L'espace rural :
a) Les espaces ruraux dans le monde.
b) Les mutations agricoles et l'espace rural.
c) Les relations entre les villes et les campagnes.
5° La géographie du développement :
a) Les pays émergents.
b) Les pays les moins avancés (PMA).
c) Les problèmes urbains dans les pays en voie de développement (PVD).
d) Les problèmes environnementaux dans les PVD.
6° La géopolitique :
a) Les nouveaux enjeux géopolitiques.
b) La géopolitique de l'Europe et de ses voisins.
7° La géographie de l'environnement :
a) L'interaction entre milieux naturels et sociétés : le risque environnemental.
b) Les paysages et les territoires.
8° L'aménagement et l'urbanisme :
a) L'aménagement du territoire français et européen.
b) Le développement régional.
c) Les politiques urbaines et l'urbanisme.
```

Intento el siguiente pero no parace que modifica cualquier cosa :

```
def read_first_letter(filename):
    tags = ['a)','b)','c)','d)','e)','f)','g)']
    """
    Solution to change
    characters of the string
    read from a file.
    """
    with open(filename) as fd:
        x = fd.readlines()

        for tag in tags:
            if tag in x:
                print(x.replace(tag, '\item'))
        print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = "historyProgram.txt"
    read_first_letter(filename)
```

En efecto :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/useful$ python changeFirstChars.py 
['I. - Histoire\n', '\n', "Le programme porte sur l'histoire de la France et du monde de 1945 à nos jours.\n", '1° La construction du monde contemporain (de 1945 aux années 1960) :\n', 'a) Le monde en 1945.\n', 'b) Le modèle communiste et son expansion mondiale.\n', 'c) Puissance et influence du modèle américain.\n', "d) La renaissance de l'Europe et ses limites.\n", 'e) La fin des empires coloniaux.\n', 'f) Un monde bipolaire : guerre froide et coexistence pacifique.\n', '2° La croissance et la crise (des années 1950 aux années 1990) :\n', 'a) La croissance économique et la société de la prospérité (1950-1973).\n', "b) Les relations Est-Ouest à l'heure de l'équilibre.\n", "c) Le tiers-monde à l'écart de la croissance.\n", 'd) La longue crise, sa signification et ses retombées sociales.\n', "e) L'échec du modèle communiste en Europe et la fin de l'URSS.\n", "f) L'élaboration d'un nouvel ordre mondial dominé par l'hyperpuissance américaine.\n", '3° La France depuis 1945 :\n', 'a) La reconstruction politique et économique de la France après 1945.\n', "b) Les guerres coloniales et l'échec de la IVe République.\n", 'c) Naissance et consolidation de la Ve République (1958-1969).\n', 'd) La Ve République après 1969 : les expériences néo-gaullistes, libérales, socialistes.\n', "e) L'évolution de la Ve République : alternances, cohabitations, mutations (1986-2013).\n", 'f) Les mutations sociales et culturelles depuis 1945.\n', '4° Le monde au début du XXIe siècle :\n', "a) L'hyperpuissance américaine.\n", 'b) Les enjeux de la construction européenne.\n', 'c) Les destins contrastés des anciens pays socialistes.\n', 'd) La diversité des tiers-mondes : entre émergence(s) et domination(s).\n', "e) Les contrastes de l'aire asiatique et le géant chinois .\n", "f) La percée de l'islam intégriste et la menace du terrorisme.\n", '\n', 'II. - Géographie\n', '\n', '1° Les milieux naturels :\n', 'a) Les domaines climatiques et les milieux naturels.\n', 'b) Les écosystèmes.\n', '2° Les grands ensembles régionaux du monde :\n', 'a) Les aires culturelles.\n', 'b) La triade (Amérique du Nord, Europe, Asie orientale) et la globalisation.\n', "3° L'espace urbain :\n", 'a) La ville.\n', "b) L'urbanisation dans le monde.\n", 'c) Les réseaux urbains en France et en Europe.\n', "d) L'espace urbain et les sociétés urbaines.\n", "4° L'espace rural :\n", 'a) Les espaces ruraux dans le monde.\n', "b) Les mutations agricoles et l'espace rural.\n", 'c) Les relations entre les villes et les campagnes.\n', '5° La géographie du développement :\n', 'a) Les pays émergents.\n', 'b) Les pays les moins avancés (PMA).\n', 'c) Les problèmes urbains dans les pays en voie de développement (PVD).\n', 'd) Les problèmes environnementaux dans les PVD.\n', '6° La géopolitique :\n', 'a) Les nouveaux enjeux géopolitiques.\n', "b) La géopolitique de l'Europe et de ses voisins.\n", "7° La géographie de l'environnement :\n", "a) L'interaction entre milieux naturels et sociétés : le risque environnemental.\n", 'b) Les paysages et les territoires.\n', "8° L'aménagement et l'urbanisme :\n", "a) L'aménagement du territoire français et européen.\n", 'b) Le développement régional.\n', "c) Les politiques urbaines et l'urbanisme.\n"]
```

Intenté tambien :

```
def read_first_letter(filename):
    tags = ['a)','b)','c)','d)','e)','f)','g)']
    """
    Solution to change
    characters of the string
    read from a file.
    """
    with open(filename) as myfile:

        x = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

        for tag in tags:
            if tag in x:
                print(x.replace(tag, '\item'))
        print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = "historyProgram.txt"
    read_first_letter(filename)
```

Pero no funciona tampoco :

```
mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/useful$ python changeFirstChars.py 
I. - HistoireLe programme porte sur l'histoire de la France et du monde de 1945 à nos jours.1° La construction du monde contemporain (de 1945 aux années 1960) :a) Le monde en 1945.b) Le modèle communiste et son expansion mondiale.c) Puissance et influence du modèle américain.d) La renaissance de l'Europe et ses limites.e) La fin des empires coloniaux.f) Un monde bipolaire : guerre froide et coexistence pacifique.2° La croissance et la crise (des années 1950 aux années 1990) :a) La croissance économique et la société de la prospérité (1950-1973).b) Les relations Est-Ouest à l'heure de l'équilibre.c) Le tiers-monde à l'écart de la croissance.d) La longue crise, sa signification et ses retombées sociales.e) L'échec du modèle communiste en Europe et la fin de l'URSS.f) L'élaboration d'un nouvel ordre mondial dominé par l'hyperpuissance américaine.3° La France depuis 1945 :a) La reconstruction politique et économique de la France après 1945.b) Les guerres coloniales et l'échec de la IVe République.c) Naissance et consolidation de la Ve République (1958-1969).d) La Ve République après 1969 : les expériences néo-gaullistes, libérales, socialistes.e) L'évolution de la Ve République : alternances, cohabitations, mutations (1986-2013).f) Les mutations sociales et culturelles depuis 1945.4° Le monde au début du XXIe siècle :a) L'hyperpuissance américaine.b) Les enjeux de la construction européenne.c) Les destins contrastés des anciens pays socialistes.d) La diversité des tiers-mondes : entre émergence(s) et domination(s).e) Les contrastes de l'aire asiatique et le géant chinois .f) La percée de l'islam intégriste et la menace du terrorisme.II. - Géographie1° Les milieux naturels :a) Les domaines climatiques et les milieux naturels.b) Les écosystèmes.2° Les grands ensembles régionaux du monde :a) Les aires culturelles.b) La triade (Amérique du Nord, Europe, Asie orientale) et la globalisation.3° L'espace urbain :a) La ville.b) L'urbanisation dans le monde.c) Les réseaux urbains en France et en Europe.d) L'espace urbain et les sociétés urbaines.4° L'espace rural :a) Les espaces ruraux dans le monde.b) Les mutations agricoles et l'espace rural.c) Les relations entre les villes et les campagnes.5° La géographie du développement :a) Les pays émergents.b) Les pays les moins avancés (PMA).c) Les problèmes urbains dans les pays en voie de développement (PVD).d) Les problèmes environnementaux dans les PVD.6° La géopolitique :a) Les nouveaux enjeux géopolitiques.b) La géopolitique de l'Europe et de ses voisins.7° La géographie de l'environnement :a) L'interaction entre milieux naturels et sociétés : le risque environnemental.b) Les paysages et les territoires.8° L'aménagement et l'urbanisme :a) L'aménagement du territoire français et européen.b) Le développement régional.c) Les politiques urbaines et l'urbanisme.
```

El objetivo final es transformar un archivo dado en un formato Latex

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `fd.readlines()` te retorna una lista, por lo que cuando haces

```
if tag in x:
```

Lo que estás validando es que por ejemplo `a)` sea alguna de las lineas, cosa que no va a ocurrir, a menos que una sola de las líneas sea este texto. Lo que deberías hacer es iterar sobre cada linea, por ejemplo:

```
with open(filename) as fd:
    lineas = fd.readlines()
    for l in lineas:
      for tag in tags:
          if tag in l:
              l = l.replace(tag, '\item')
      print(l.strip())
```

Sino también, puedes trabajar con el texto completo del archivo y usar expresiones regular para reemplazar las etiquetas, incluso de una forma más precisa y genérica:

```
import re
def read_first_letter(filename):
    with open(filename) as fd:
        texto = fd.read()
        texto = re.sub(re.compile('^([a-zA-Z]\))(.*)', flags=re.MULTILINE), r'\item\2', texto, )
        print(texto)
```